# Laravel 5.6 query builder sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have **table 'peserta'** with structure

> - name (varchar)
> - h1 (integer)
> - h2 (integer)
> - h3 (integer)

I want select **(h1 + h2 + h3) as total** and order by ascending with limit 30. what the right query builder?

```
> $rank['rank'] = DB::table('peserta')->select('*', '(n1+n2+n3) as
> total')->limit(30)->orderBy('total', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Raw query:

```
DB::table('peserta')
   ->select(
        '*', 
       DB::raw('(n1+n2+n3) as > total')
    )
   ->limit(30)
   ->orderBy('total', 'asc')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with eloquent selectRaw method.

```
$rank['rank'] = DB::table('peserta')
                ->selectRaw('*, h1 + h2 + h3 as total')
                ->limit(30)
                ->orderBy('total', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('peserta')
 ->select('*', DB::raw('(IFNULL(h1,0) + IFNULL(h2,0)) + IFNULL(h3,0) as total'))
 ->orderBy('total')
 ->limit(30)
 ->get();
```

I am setting 0 if one of the column value is null otherwise total will be giving you null value if one of h1,h2 or h3 is null.